# PlayFramework 2.1: Making a GET request with WS.url including a given string as the body

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to issue a GET request towards an ElasticSearch instance, which requires a json-encoded string as the *body* of the request. My impression from the API is that there is no way to add a string as the body of a GET request -- am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There was a [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/WS.url%2420get%2420body/play-framework/z0FK4-rD8aU/Oucsm-ApAvcJ) in the Play framework mailing list, that I missed while searching.

So this is a known (and debated) issue.